# (react native) how to set multiple components for an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, native

```
const Card = ({text1, text2, text3}) => (
<CardView>
      <Text> {text1}</Text>
      <Text> {text2} </Text>
      <Text> {text3} </Text> 
  </CardView>

);
```

Is this the right way to set the components for this object I've created? It works with one "variable" like

```
 const Card = ({ text1 }) => (
  <CardView>
      <Text> {text1} </Text>
  </CardView>

);
```

but for some reason is not working when I have multiple "texts". I'm calling it as such

```
 <Card text1 = {text1} text2 = {text2} text3 = {text3} />
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You've got invalid syntax?

Comment: You are missing start tag for `</View>`. Also, alternate approach: instead of accepting different props, accept 1 prop say data-source which accepts array. Loop over it and create your component

Comment: Sorry, I removed some code to isolate the problem. The </View> should not be there.

Comment: @Rajesh if I wanted to accept different props, how would I do this?

Comment: What error do you get? Can you please elaborate as if you are simply trying to do this it works fine.